# PayPal button / hidden inputs in html email

Tags: html, email, input, paypal, hidden

I have a working PayPal button on my website. It's not hosted by PayPal, I just wrote the code myself. It looks like this:

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='cmd' value='_donations'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='business' value='myemail@myhost.com'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='item_name' value='$item'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='item_number' value='$number'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='amount' value='$payment'>
<input type='image' src='http://www.switchonthree.com/imgs/buynow.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>
<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>
</form>
```

Works great. When I take the same code and embed it in an html email, the button is there and it looks fine, but the link just goes to the PayPal homepage. It appears that none of the hidden inputs are working. Can you have hidden inputs in an email? Is there a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: just to clarify, is this EXACTLY what you paste into the email, or did you put $item $number and $payment in the place of real values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a security feature from Palpal. It could be that submitting the form in email does not result in a referer address that palpay reads. This is, it is blank.

So I think Paypal does not trust the form post and is redirecting you to their front page.

In general, posting a form via email seems strange and insecure to me.

The workaround is to direct users to a website to complete the purchase of which they would submit the form you have above from that website.

Comment: Yes, I created a separate webpage, just for the form. Then I had my email button direct the user to that webpage, passing along the hidden input data in the form of php variables. Then I wrote a script to automatically submit the form on page load. So now (except for the minor delay of a redirect) I have achieved the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most modern email clients won't allow/support forms as they see it as a security risk, so its practice is not recommended.

I think the problem you are having is that you are doing a POST instead of a GET so changing it to the following may do the trick

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='get'>
```

see this [article](http://www.b2bemailmarketing.com/2005/10/using_forms_in_.html)

Read this article "[Do forms work in HTML emails?](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/)" from CampaignMonitor for more info

In this [article](http://mailchimp.blogs.com/blog/2005/08/placing_forms_i.html) from MailChimp, they make a good suggestion to have an online version of your form which can be linked to from the email.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use forms in email. Ever.
You could use https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=xxxx&amount=xxxx&item_name=xxxx but really, why not go for a PayPal 'hosted button'? That way you at least won't be exposing the amount to the public, leaving it open to manipulation.

Simply set up the hosted button (tick 'Host button with PayPal' in Step 2 of the button creation tool), and at the end of it you'll be shown the code along with an 'E-mail' tab with a shortened email link for your button which you can use in emails.